# Group by query checking status over multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks as below

My data table looks like this:

```
client_id   Status
   1         a
   1         b
   1         d
   1         e
   2         a
   2         d
   3         a
   3         b
   3         e
   4         a
   4         d
   5         b
```

I need to group by client where status has values both a and d

The result set from above should return

```
client_id     a_d_Flag
  1             Yes
  2             Yes
  3             No
  4             Yes
  5             No
```

Query :

```
SELECT c.client
    , CASE WHEN c.Status = 'a' AND c.status = 'd'
    THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
    END AS a_d_Flag
FROM client_details c
GROUP BY c.client
HAVING c.Status = 'a' AND c.status = 'd'
```

Comment: To group by you need to perform some form of aggregation...

Comment: And `HAVING` is intended to operate on an aggregation, otherwise its just a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a case expression to check for `Status` and count for  `a` or `d`

```
select client_id, 
       case when count(case when Status in ('a', 'd') then Status end) = 2
            then 'Yes'
            else 'No'
            end
from   client_details
group by client_id
```

That is assuming that you does not have duplicate `Status` for a `client_id`.

If you have such as like

```
3         a
3         a
3         b
```

change the `count` to `count(distinct case ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  cd.client_id, 
  a_d_Flag =
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN cd.Status = 'a' THEN 1 END) > 0
          AND COUNT(CASE WHEN cd.Status = 'd' THEN 1 END) > 0
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END
FROM client_details cd
GROUP BY
  cd.client_id;
```

Note that this method handles duplicate rows of `a` or `d` correctly.